# is it possible to assign a Microsoft Teams App to a user using the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I can see the Graph API call to [assign a Teams App to a given team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0), but I can't see a call to assign an App to a given user.

Is this possible using the Graph API?

If not, are there any other ways to perform this programmatically?

Comment: Graph APIs to achieve this is currently under development.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging#install-the-app-for-your-users

This capability is now available via the Graph API